# Error: Could not find or load main class main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: main)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Here is my code:-

```java
public class Main {

    public static float radius = 10.0f;
    public static void main(String[] a){
        Circle c1 = new Circle();
        c1.radius = 10.0f;
        System.out.println("area of circle = " + c1.area());
    }
}

class Circle{

    public float radius;
    public float area(){
        return 3.141f * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

When I try to **Run Code** on Visual Studio Code I am getting the following error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class main
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: main)

but when I click on **Debug Java** the code gives the output: **area of circle = 314.1** which is the desired output.

I actually wants to what's the problem which is causing error while running the code.

Comment: maybe some cached version of the class? try cleaning all previous classes

Comment: Is there a case mismatch with the file naming?

Comment: The file name needs to match the main Class name.

Comment: "try cleaning all previous classes"
It didnot worked at all.

Comment: "The file name needs to match the main Class name."
The file name is exactly the same as main class name.

Comment: Does your class have a package statement at the start? Is the filename actually `Main.class` (and not `main.class`)?

Comment: I have saved the file with name "Main.java" after compilation 2 files are created automatically in the same directory by the compiler named as "Main.class" and "Circle.class".

Comment: Open a new empty folder then create `Main.java`, I can **Run Code** successfully. Open Command Palette and choose `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`, if not help, please try coding in a new folder.

Comment: Windows has a case-insensitive file system but Java is case-sensitive. Remove the old .java file and save again, making sure the file name is the same as the class name (plus the `.java` extension).